# Using Liquibase and cherry-picking changesets

Tags: development-environment, liquibase

So I want to use liquibase as a replacement for SQL scripts for preparing databases in different development environment (SIT->UAT->PROD). The plan is to execute the liquibase update (with some other parameters in place if necessary), before start doing the testing.

The caveat is, all files (including liquibase XML) that are to be submitted to UAT and PROD must have been frozen; i.e. there could be no change for any files that has successfully passed SIT. Is there any way I can do this, so that in UAT I can only execute changesets which have successfully passed SIT (and similarly, in PROD I can only execute changesets which have successfully passed UAT), without actually altering the XML file on liquibase?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

There are several issues which are inherent inside the current development cycle:

1. It would be redundant to ask the developers to run SIT again, this time with  context=SIT being put inside.
2. Developer(s) only wanting to test their own changesets in the UAT. So a developer is only responsible for his own changesets; meaning they don't want to run others' changesets, even if these changesets have successfully passed SIT. Same issue also applies for UAT -> PROD.

Sorry I was not clear on this issue beforehand. I was tasked to implement Liquibase on my current workplace, and I don't have a really good picture of what's really happening in the cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquibase does not allow you to pick certain changeSets to execute. The main reason for this is because the order that changes run against a database can make a big difference. Normally it doesn't help to have developers run just their changeSets because the database changes created by others are still needed by the application.

I think the most common way to handle your scenario is to rely on the same version control practices you use for your codebase. Liquibase is designed as a simple text format so that the changelog files can be stored in version control along with your code. Then, you can have branches for UAT and PROD and you can control what is going into those branches, including what changeSets are in the changelogs.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option wouuld be to use contexts (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html). ChangeSets that have passed SIT can be marked as context="sit". Then when you update UAT and PROD run with context=sit and only the tagged changesets will execute.

Comment: We can't mark anything after SIT has passed, @Nathan. It would be redundant to ask the developers to run SIT again, this time with context=SIT being put inside.

And also, there's the multiple problem of developer(s) only wanting to test their own changesets in the UAT. So a developer is only responsible for his own changesets; meaning they don't want to run others' changesets, even if these changesets have successfully passed SIT. 

Sorry I was not clear on this issue; I will update this on the description.

Comment: OK. My assumption was that your SIT process was going through the changeSets and wanted to mark the ones that have been OKed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that based on your valid requirements that all scripts have to be frozen in the file-based version control which is external to Liquibase you have a major challenge here.

Liquibase cannot guarantee that files are frozen - it is not for Liquibase to know that.

You are welcome to review [DBmaestro Teamwork](http://www2.dbmaestro.com/l/11742/2014-04-02/vrnkh), which enables you an enforced version control on your database objects (which guarantees that the repository and workspace database are in sync). Also generating the delta scripts handles all the merges (between different environments, UAT critical fixes, branches) from changes not originating from the development env.

Disclaimer -I'm working at DBmaestro